# Create a loop of Multiple li tag where html code is same but the value is different

Tags: php, html, wordpress, loops, conditional-statements

In my custom template of WordPress theme i have around 20+ li tag element where the html code is same and value is different. and i am creating separate condition for each element.

Is it possible to set a  loop of this code, so that i should not create every li tag a separate condition and less my html code.

```
        <?php $user_birthday = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'user_birthday', true); ?>
          <?php if(!empty($user_birthday)) { ?>
            <li>
              <span class="min-w-[100px] mr-2 inline-block font-bold"
                >Birthday:</span
              ><span class="text-slate-500"><?php echo $user_birthday; ?></span>
            </li>
            <?php } ?>

            <?php $user_age = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'user_age', true);
            if(!empty($user_age)) { ?>
            <li>
              <span class="min-w-[100px] mr-2 inline-block font-bold"
              >Age:</span
              ><span class="text-slate-500"><?php echo $user_age; ?></span>
            </li>
            <?php  } ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop the content

```php
<?php 
$user_birthday = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'user_birthday', true);
$user_age = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'user_age', true);

$items = [
  'Birthday' => $user_birthday,
  'Age' => $user_age
];

foreach ($items as $label => $value) {
  if (!empty($value)) echo "<li><span class=\"min-w-[100px] mr-2 inline-block font-bold\">$label:</span><span class=\"text-slate-500\">$value</span></li>";
}
?>
```